# using control defined in resourcedictionary

Tags: silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am creating a Silverlight project in which i have a silverlight page.
The page consist of a control which needs to be displayed/hidden at runtime based on certain logic, so it cannot be placed under any container control. To solve this, i placed the control in page's resources dictionary and specified its x:key. This is for 2 reasons:
1. i specified earlier that control is displayed/hidden at runtime thru logic
2. the control does not supports XAML Style

Now i have another page that requires the same control. so i want to place the control through resorce dictionary and not creating through control markup

So can anybody tell me how to place control that i defined in page's resource dictionary. I can move this control to application's global resource dictionary. this will not be a problem for me.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanx in advane

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DataTemplate` and put the control in it, then load that data template as the content template of a content control that you have in your page.

But, it's not supposed to work like that. What inhibits you from placing the control in the layout and controlling it's visibility according to your logic?